# angular2: routing by code after Observable success

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I know that using `routerLink` directive, I'm able to route to a destination:

```
<a [routerLink]=" ['/app'] ">LogOut</a>
```

This is an static way to create links on your website.

Nevertheless, sometimes the route must be done according if an `http` request has been processed correctly:

```
public createAccount():void {
    this.clearAlerts();
    this.commty.create(this.form.value.mail, this.form.value.passwd)
    .subscribe(
        (result: any) => {       // <-- handler for result
            >>>>>>>>>> go to '/app' route   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        },
        (error: any) => {        // <-- handler for error
            this.addAlert(error.message);
        }
    );
}
```

I guess there must be a way to do that using typescript code...
Could you provide me an example or any documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
router.navigate(['/app'])
```

but for it you need to import and inject `Router` in component

```
import {Router}     from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: '<h1>Hello</h1>',
})
export class AppComponent  {
    constructor(private router: Router){
    router.navigate(['/app'])

    }
}
```